# Visual Basic run webbrowser with java

Tags: vb.net, rs

I'm trying to make a `Runescape Client` in Visual Basic, but when I run http://www.runescape.com/game in a web browser it tells me to install `java`

It brings up an error saying:

```
*An error has occurred in the script on this page.
line: 48
Char: 325
Error: Expected ')'
code: 0
URL: http://www.runescape.com/game
Do you want to continue running the scripts on this page?
(Yes/No)*
```

I need a way to run `Runescape` inside a visual basic Application.

**Is there any way to add *java* to the web browser?**

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You of course will have to install Java.  Just once, don't write code to do it.

Comment: The error message looks like a **JavaScript** error, which is not the same thing as Java.  Just out of curiosity, why did you tag your question with vba, split and rs as well as vb.net?  vb.net and vba are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a JS error, the easiest fix is to input in the Form load,

```
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

Hopefully that works?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting [this error](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-do-internet-explorer-script-errors#1TC=windows-7), which is a JavaScript error on the page, not a Java error on your machine.

[image: JavaScript error]

To resolve, you need to clear the "Display a notification about every script error" check box in the Advanced section of the Internet Options menu.  [Here's a lengthy article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311288/en-us) on Microsoft Support describing how to access and change the Internet Options via VB.Net.

The relevant code from that page to access the Internet Options:

```
Public Sub InternetOptions()
    Dim cmdt As IOleCommandTarget
    Dim o As Object

    Try
        cmdt = CType(GetDocument(), IOleCommandTarget)
        cmdt.Exec(cmdGUID, Convert.ToUInt32(MiscCommandTarget.Options), _
        Convert.ToUInt32(SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT), o, o)
    Catch
        ' NOTE: Due to the way this CMDID is handled inside of Internet Explorer,
        ' this Catch block will always fire, even though the dialog
        ' and its operations completed successfully. Suppressing this
        ' error will cause no harm to your host.
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the webbrowser ScriptErrorsSuppressed property to true and thats all